# Remove repetitions of patterns in a string

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Let's say I have the following `string`:

```
aabccd
```

I'd like to find and remove all patterns that are repeated. In this example, one **a** is followed by another one, which is a repetition. Same thing about **cc**.

The final string would be:

```
bd
```

Another example: **banana** => **ba** (because two **an** or two **na**).

Here's the algorithm I've come up with:

> Splitting the string in two halves and taking the biggest one
>
> Let's say it has a length of 4; I look in the other half if it's there
>
> Next turn of loop, I shift my string from one character (but still of
>   length 4) until I loop all the possible patterns
>
> Then I reduce the half by one character (so length 3) and start again
>
> // etc.

It would do something like this:

**helloguys** -> **hell** -> **ello** -> **llog**

And some code, not working as it should:

```
std::string processWord(std::string word)
{
    // Split word in the two halves
    std::string firstHalf = word.substr(0, word.size() / 2);
    std::string secondHalf = word.substr(firstHalf.size());

    // Check if the tiniest half is present in the biggest one (firstHalf will be eitheir lower or equal to secondHalf)
    if (secondHalf.find(firstHalf) != std::string::npos)
    {
       std::cout << firstHalf << " is found in " << secondHalf << std::endl;
       // Remove firstHalf from secondHalf
       word.replace(word.find(firstHalf), firstHalf.size(), "");
       std::cout << word << std::endl;
       return word;
   }

   for (size_t i = 1; i < secondHalf.size(); ++i)
   {
       // Get secondHalf minus one character at each loop turn to check occurences
       std::string occurence = secondHalf.substr(0, secondHalf.size() - i);
       // Mark the first occurence
       size_t startIndex = indexOf(word, occurence);
       // Mark the last occurence
       size_t lastIndex = startIndex;
       int totalOccurences = 1;

       // As long as there are occurences following each other, we continue
       // Example: "anandgdfgd". We see "an" twice. But it would not work with "anshfsduihsuan" since they are not following each other
       while (word.find(occurence, lastIndex + occurence.size()) != std::string::npos)
       {
           lastIndex += occurence.size();
           totalOccurences++;
       }

       std::ostringstream oss;
       oss << "[" << totalOccurences << "*" << occurence << "]";

       word.replace(startIndex, lastIndex, oss.str());
  }
  // Some code is missing here
  return word;
}
```

I'm sure this problem has already been solved but I can't find anything. Any tips?

Comment: What to do with `baaacd`, `baanan`, and `baab`? The first contains 3 chars, in the second removing double `a` excludes removing `anan`, in the third removing `aa` leads to 'bb' pair - should it be removed too?

Comment: @MBo: good questions. The first would remove the three 'a'. The second depends on the algorithm, it would only do one of the two solutions. Same answer for the third. I think one sweep is enough.

Comment: Without at least some restrictions, this is undoubtedly impractical. With at least some restrictions, it's pretty much asking for LZ* compression.

Answer (score 0):

Clear rules have not been defined yet, but I think that building [Suffix Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array) is good starting point.   You can compare neighbour suffixes, find length of common starting parts and make decision - what substrings are the best candidates for removing.